# How to use which?

Tags: grammaticality, which-that

Is it grammatically correct to say:

> A(x) and B(X) are the velocity and the temperature of the solution which we need to find them.

Many thanks

Comment: What is *them*? Are "they" mentioned in a previous sentence?

Comment: No, does not mention in a previous sentence. Them refer to the velocity A(X) and the temperature B(X). Is that correct?

Comment: No, that's not correct. _Which_ **means** _them_, and it gets moved to the beginning of the clause.  This sentence could be pronounced with _to find them_ as a purpose infinitive, meaning _in order to find them_, but that means that _them_ does not refer to `A(X)` and `B(X)`.

Comment: How can I write this sentence then?

Comment: So how about if I write like this (( Ax) and B(X) are the velocity and the temperature of the solution which we need to find)). Is it correct now?

Answer (score 0):

You have two alternatives:

> A(x) and B(x) are the velocity and the temperature of the solution, which we need to find.
>
> A(x) and B(x) are the velocity and the temperature of the solution that we need to find.

The first means:

> A(x) and B(x) are the velocity and the temperature of the solution. We need to find them.

The second means:

> A(x) and B(x) are ( the velocity and the temperature of the solution that we need to find ).